# Margin appears but does not show up in inspector

Tags: html, css

I was looking at this webpage http://bulma.io/documentation/elements/buttons/, and I've observed that there are spaces between the buttons.

[image]

I've tried to inspect the elements and parent elements with the Chrome developer tools, but I'm unable to discern what causes the spacing between these buttons. Can someone help me out?

Comment: This is because of default space between `inline-block` elements. The buttons are `inline-block` so there would be a default space between them.`inline-block` elements are considered to be text so the new line character between them in HTML would make a space between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white space is causing the spacing between the buttons. If you want to remove that, you have to remove the white space in between:

```
<button>button 1</button><button>button 2</button>
```

Or you can use CSS to fix it by using float:left or float:right.